# Using arrays to summarize survey results

Tags: c, arrays

**This example from How to program c book**

Forty students were asked to rate the quality of the food in the
    student cafeteria on a scale of 1 to 10 (1 means awful and 10 means
    excellent). Place the 40 responses in an integer array and summarize
    the results of the poll.

---

I am stuck in understanding the algorithm used in this example and could not understand it , kindly if you can simplify it.thanks in advance

```
// Analyzing a student poll.
#include <stdio.h>
#define RESPONSES_SIZE 40 // define array sizes
#define FREQUENCY_SIZE 11
int main( void ) {
size_t answer; // counter to loop through 40 responses
size_t rating; // counter to loop through frequencies 1-10
// initialize frequency counters to 0
int frequency[ FREQUENCY_SIZE ] = { 0 };
// place the survey responses in the responses array
int  responses[ RESPONSES_SIZE ] = { 1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5, 9, 7, 8, 10,
1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 10, 3, 8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6,
5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 6, 8, 10 };
// for each answer, select value of an element of array responses
// and use that value as subscript in array frequency to
// determine element to increment
for ( answer = 0; answer < RESPONSES_SIZE; ++answer )
{
    frequency[ responses [ answer ] ]=frequency[ responses [ answer ] ]+1;
} // end for
// display results
printf( "%s%17s\n", "Rating", "Frequency" );
// output the frequencies in a tabular format
for ( rating = 1; rating < FREQUENCY_SIZE; ++rating )
{
    printf( "%6d%17d\n", rating, frequency[ rating ] );
} // end for
// end main
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty self explanatory. The code is filled with helpful comments. I don't think you can get any better explanation. If anyone tried they'd be repeating what is being said in the comments at best.

Comment: What exactly is that you don't understand? this part "frequency[ responses [ answer ] ]=frequency[ responses [ answer ] ]+1;" ?

Comment: exactly this is what in need some explanation to understand@dreamcrash

Comment: well @dasblinkenlight just provided the explanation :)

Comment: Note that the `frequency` array has 11 elements, but `frequency[0]` is unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about as simple as it gets.

```
for ( answer = 0; answer < RESPONSES_SIZE; ++answer )
{
    frequency[ responses [ answer ] ]=frequency[ responses [ answer ] ]+1;
}
```

... loops through the `answer` array, and for each value in there, updates the `frequency` element for that value. It could be made slightly clearer with:

```
for ( answer = 0; answer < RESPONSES_SIZE; ++answer )
{
    int response = responses[answer];
    frequency[response]=frequency[response]+1;
}
```

(This is called an "extract local variable" refactoring).

So if the first value in `responses` is 5, then the first thing it will do is replace the 0 in `frequency[5]` with `0 + 1 == 1`.

Then having filled `frequency` with facts:

```
for ( rating = 1; rating < FREQUENCY_SIZE; ++rating )
{
    printf( "%6d%17d\n", rating, frequency[ rating ] );
}
```

... loops through `frequency` printing the index and the content of each element.

Comment: spent hours to get it.Thanks@slim

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand the code rewrite this loop

```
for ( answer = 0; answer < RESPONSES_SIZE; ++answer )
{
    frequency[ responses [ answer ] ]=frequency[ responses [ answer ] ]+1;
} // end for
```

the following way:)

```
for ( answer = 0; answer < RESPONSES_SIZE; ++answer )
{
    rating = responses[ answer ];

    switch ( rating )
    {
    case 1:
        frequency[1] = frequency[1] + 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        frequency[2] = frequency[2] + 1;
        break;
    case 3:
        frequency[3] = frequency[3] + 1;
        break;
    case 4:
        frequency[4] = frequency[4] + 1;
        break;
    case 5:
        frequency[5] = frequency[5] + 1;
        break;
    case 6:
        frequency[6] = frequency[6] + 1;
        break;
    case 7:
        frequency[7] = frequency[7] + 1;
        break;
    case 8:
        frequency[8] = frequency[8] + 1;
        break;
    case 9:
        frequency[9] = frequency[9] + 1;
        break;
    case 10:
        frequency[10] = frequency[10] + 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: according to code efficiency.what is better ? using switch case or array notation ?@Vlad from Moscow

Comment: @Elhaw Specially for such advanced programmers as you I wrote "JUST to understand the code " It seems it was not enough.